# Edit Vim windows size dynamicaly with a hotkey

Tags: vim, editor

In the vimrc file you can set the number of colums and lines you want your windows to be with the commands:

```
set columns=*
set lines=*
```

But how can I dynamicaly edit that. Like having a mapped hotkey that for example increase the value of one of them or decrease the value of one of them.

For example:

```
set colums=80
<C-B>
```

and then the columns number value is 81

(The question isn't about 'nnoremap' but the command that can increase the value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
let &columns=&columns+20
```

The `&` sign can be used to get the value of a setting.

Comment: I get this answer from Vim: `E521: Number required after =: columns=(&columns+20)`. What i did is a little script with 2 variable height and width. And i edit them like this `nnoremap <F6> :let width=width-1 \| :execute "set columns=".width<CR>`

Comment: ups my bad, ironically the solution is also the `&` sign. I've updated my answer

Comment: so what is the difference between `let &columns` and `set columns`?

Comment: In short, `&` tells vim that you are referencing an option not a variable. `set` does this automatically, but only taktes a single literal. `let` must be told to that something is a vim option, but can parse vimscript. Have a look here for more information: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html#options-as-variables